# Autoloaded vs lua functions: which is faster/more efficient?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, vimscript-lua, autoload, plugin

I'm creating a neovim plugin written in Lua, and I have to react to the `BufAdd` and `BufUnload` events with a function call. I have 3 options:

1. write the function in Lua (like the rest of the plugin) and call it via:

```
autocmd BufAdd,BufUnload * lua require('myplugin').myfunction(args)
```

2. write the function in Vimscript and place it in the `autoload` folder:

```
autocmd BufAdd,BufUnload * call myplugin#myfunction(args)
```

3. write the function in Vimscript and place it in the `plugin` folder:

```
autocmd BufAdd,BufUnload * call MyPluginMyFunction(args)
```

I'd like to know which one is the best from a speed/efficiency standpoint. The function is question is around ~10 lines of non computationally intensive code.

Comment: "Autoload" (just like "require") = load-on-demand. It's nothing about speed. 10 lines is a negligible amount even if you have 1000 open/close operations. Especially as they are all triggered by a (dreadfully slow) organic creature. If there's no other reason then simply putting all code into a file where autocommands could be even more preferable.

Comment: If you want to have your function available for Vim and not only neovim, I would put it into an autoloaded folder. But that makes only sense, if there are cases when the function does not need to be loaded on startup. I don't know how fast the lua functions are, but those hurt my eyes.

Comment: Define *faster* and *more efficient*. Faster at what? To execute? To load? Etc.